# Java class file not generated for new activity in Android Studio

Tags: android-activity, android-studio

I'm just starting out with Android development and in general I keep hitting brick walls that seem to have more to do with the IDEs then the anything else.  I started out with Eclipse but it kept corrupting my projects and other weird errors.  Now I'm trying Android Studio which seems more stable but again a brick wall:

After following the android tutorial to the letter to create the hello world app I tried to add a new activity.  The xml file was created fine but the java class file did not show up under src like it did in eclipse.  What gives?  This is demoralizing me.  I long for the days of writing C code for microcontrollers using just an editor and cmd line.

Thanks.

Comment: I am running into the same issue while trying to mess with the NDK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto File -> Settings -> Compiler
2. check use external build then
3. rebuild project

Answer (score -1):

Update your Eclipse ADT plugin, then export project and the import in Android Studio.
And follow the below link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html